# Vec<Vec<...>> Moving items between child vectors

Tags: rust

Having

```
let mut stacks = vec![
    vec!['A', 'B'], 
    vec!['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
];

println!("vec: {:?}", stacks);
```

which prints

```
vec: [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]
```

I would like to move 'E' and 'F' from the 2nd vector to the first vector
so that the result is:

```
vec: [['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'D']]
```

The only way I was able to do it is with a temporary helper vector:

```
let col_from = 1;
let col_to = 0;
let n_to_move = 2;

let len = stacks[col_from].len();

let crates = stacks[col_from].drain(len - n_to_move..);

let mut temp = Vec::new();
temp.extend(crates);

stacks[col_to].extend(temp);

println!("vec: {:?}", stacks);
```

This works, but I wonder if there is more concise way to achieve this.

Comment: Define 'concise' in this context? There are ways that prevent the temporary vector, but they most likely will require a couple more lines of code because this is a complicated ownership situation.

Comment: @Finomnis Yes, it's mainly about temporary `len` and `temp` helpers. Tbh I'm after an idiomatic solution rather then a concise one.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, your problem is that you were trying to get two mutable references to `stacks` at the same time, so that you can mutate two elements. Something like this:

```
stacks[col_to].extend(stacks[col_from].drain(stacks[col_from].len() - n_to_move..));
```

This isn't allowed using indices because if the indices are the same then you'd have two mutable references to the same data, and the compiler can't statically check that.

Instead, you can use `slice::split_at_mut`, which gives you two mutable (non-overlapping) slices. Then you can get the parts you need from those.

The code might look something like this:

```
// This won't work if the columns are the same, but it also wouldn't make sense as an operation
assert!(col_from != col_to);

let (src, dest) = if col_from < col_to {
    let (a, b) = stacks.split_at_mut(col_to);
    (&mut a[col_from], &mut b[0])
} else {
    let (a, b) = stacks.split_at_mut(col_from);
    (&mut b[0], &mut a[col_to])
};
dest.extend(src.drain(src.len() - n_to_move..));
```

It's hard to argue that this is "more concise" than your code, but it does at least avoid copying any data or new allocations.